# How do I get to choose year and month along with date in SSRS Date Picker (Calendar) Control?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I see the date picker (calendar) control on my report giving out an option to pick dates as parameters for a report.  However if the user want to select an older date (01/01/2000) through calendar,  he/she has to scroll back month at a time all the way to Jan 2000 month to select 1st date.  Is there a way to incorporate year and month picker into the control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible using the default control.

I believe you could create a custom report i.e. by creating an ASP.net application for example and embedding the Report Viewer Control. You could then create a custom implementation of a calendar/date picker component in order to have more refined control over the behaviour.

I also believe Dundas have a custom Calendar control for Reporting Services

Further Reading:

[Report Viewer Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(VS.80).aspx)

[Dundas Calendar](http://www.dundas.com/Products/Calendar/RS/Why/index.aspx)

Comment: I already have the report viewer control on an ASP page.  How do I customize the width of parameter text box within the control?  Until now I couldn't find suitable answers through my search.